# How to copy Microsoft account profile data into AzureAD external guest account after redeeming an invitation

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have an application where we need to "onboard" external users into AzureAD via a controlled email invitation process.

So we are using the [create invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call via the Graph API, where we specify the email we want to onboard and an inviteRedirectUrl that will be called when the invitation is accepted

```
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "some@email.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://some-redirect-uri"
}
```

We don't let Microsoft send the invitation email but use the `inviteRedeemUrl` returned by the call to put it in a custom well branded email allowing the user to sign up with the above email adres (that is pre-filled and read-only).

Great.

When the user clicks the link he needs to login into his/her Microsoft account or create a new one if one does not exist for that email. After that an external guest account is created in AzureAD and Microsoft redirects to our application at `inviteRedirectUrl`.

On the AzureAD side however the external guest user created in Azure AD does not contain a firstname / lastname, despite the fact that the Microsoft account does contain a firstname / lastname.

Is there a standard way to "copy over" this profile data (firstname , lastname , preferred language) into the AzureAD external guest user, or is that something we need to build into our application itself ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Repro in our environment,

Post Invitation via Email address, will not update the First Name and Last name also by sending the Post Call with Givename and SurName.

Options 1:

Using Patch Operation Update the required details

[image]

Reference : Update User:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Option 2:

Use the below PowerShell script to update the User Details

```html
set-azureaduser -ObjectId 0cXXXXX-6ab3-475e-b1e8-d5XXXXX-XXXXX -givenname testxx -surname userxx
```

Additionally try with self-service sign-up user flow to an app using reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow